# Redirect Add to cart button to cart page

Tags: cart, addtocart

IF we click on "Buy now " button in view page

its redirecting to cart page. we are using following code :

```
<button class="button buy-now" onclick=”location.href =’{{config path=”web/unsecure/base_url”}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1′”>
<span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Buy Now</span></span></button>
```

we are using following code for "Add to cart" button, what we need is if we click on "add to cart" button,

**than it should redirect to cart page.**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" 
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

**edit**

JS code :

```
 productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (('undefined' != typeof productAddToCartFormOld) && productAddToCartFormOld) {
                if (Catalog.Map.active) {
                    Catalog.Map.hideHelp();
                }
                if (productAddToCartForm.qty && $('qty')) {
                    $('qty').value = productAddToCartForm.qty;
                }
                parentResult = productAddToCartFormOld.submit();
                return false;
            }
            if(window.opener) {
                var parentButton = button;
                new Ajax.Request(this.form.action, {
                    parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'GET'},
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                        window.opener.focus();
                        if (parentButton && parentButton.href) {
                            setPLocation(parentButton.href, true);
                            Catalog.Map.hideHelp();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                if (!form.getAttribute('action')) {
                   form.action = productAddToCartForm.action;
                }
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    throw e;
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: On "Buy Now" button what action you needed?

Comment: Buty now is fine, if i click on "Add to cart", it should redirect to cart page

Comment: I remember this can be achieved by admin. Did you try with Sales -> Checkout -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart ?

Comment: actually we are using 2 add to cart buttons, one button for add to cart and another one for Buy now.

I will use add to cart functionailty and put the text "Buy Now"

Comment: You can try this answer of mine : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/i-want-two-functionalities-together/97922#97922

Comment: @Prateek add to cart.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/acxuPen7

view.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/FszY9Grk please check i added your code in my site, but its not working for me, seems i didt placed a code in proper place

Comment: Both button redirect to cart page? Any ajax product addtocart  extension in your store?

Comment: @PrashantValanda no only one button need to redirect to cart page. yes, we are using Ajax add to cart button

Comment: Buy now button redirect to cart page right? Add to Cart not redirect to cart page it will add product using ajax

Comment: @PrashantValanda you are right

Comment: now also we have same kind of feature.  but i am facing this problem : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103014/shipping-charges-are-not-working-for-buy-now-button so i decided to use 2 add to cart buttons and one button redirect to cart page

Comment: First, input tag will go inside the form somewhere. Second, you have copied the exact JS function at the end of view.phtml file, you should make changes suggested there in the function you already have in place.

Comment: can you please tell after which line ,i have to place the input tag

Comment: In any line that is inside the `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: i placed below this line : `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`

Comment: i updated the question with our JS code, please check : /skin/frontend/base/default/js/msrp.js

Comment: i sucessfully placed add to cart and buy now button using your link :

now buy now button is not redirecting to cart page, please help me

Comment: @Prateek please give me updated js code

Comment: Just went through the site link you mentioned earlier, and it is working correctly for me. Please check again at your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your js code with default magento code as below

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                       form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Comment: sorry still its not working : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html)

Comment: Disable extension Em_Ajaxcart and try again

Comment: still not working

Comment: Its working for me i have just checked on your store

Comment: pls check with above link

Comment: add to cart button redirect to cart page for me.

Comment: no replaced the old code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36548/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-prashant-valanda).

Comment: @PrashantValanda How can i solve the add to cart button error,https://justpaste.it/6fi1f

Comment: @Rathinam which error? please post a question with proper detail so anyone can help you

Comment: I can't get the error, if i click add to cart button nothing will happen.

Comment: may be your add to cart code have some issue. can you please post code in question